# passing a function which makes ajax requests to $.when .done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, function, deferred

I want to generate ajax requests on the fly, but I want to make sure I get a callback after they have all completed, so I want to wrap them within a .when .done statement like the following:

```
$.when(function(){
        $.each(oOptions, function(){
            var filePath = this.filePath,
            dataType = this.dataType;

            $.ajax({
                url : filePath,
                dataType : dataType
            });
        });
    })
    .done(function(){
        console.log('success');

        console.log(arguments);
    })
    .fail(function(){
        console.log('failed');
    });
```

where my options is an array of objects containing the filepath and datatype for each ajax request I want to make simultaneously. this code will return success, but the arguments is just a function, and the ajax requests never go through. any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass a function to `$.when`, while you should pass one or more `Deferred`s. You could fill an array with deferreds and pass that to `$.when` as arguments:

```
var deferreds = [];

$.each(oOptions, function() {
    var filePath = this.filePath,
    dataType = this.dataType;

    deferreds.push($.ajax({
        url : filePath,
        dataType : dataType
    }));
});

// use the array elements as arguments using apply
$.when.apply($, deferreds)
.done(function(){
    console.log('success');

    console.log(arguments);
})
.fail(function(){
    console.log('failed');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have to put the "done" logic into the $.ajax call arguments as the success function? I mean something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  url : filePath,
  dataType : dataType,
  success: function(){
    console.log('success');
  }
});
```

Since the ajax calls are made asynchronously, the done() could be called before the ajax calls have completed...

Comment: one point of .when .done is to allow for a callback to all the ajax requests